# The string is missing the terminator: '. inside WindowsServerCore container

Tags: powershell, docker

I've an issue running a Script in a windowsservercore:10.0.14393.206 image that is used to build a .NET project. I need to manually change the location of some .dll files from package to Web/Bin with a Powershell script but I get the error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

The script is as follows:

```
$srcdir = "packages";
$destdir = "Web\Bin";
md $destdir;
$files = (Get-ChildItem $srcdir -Recurse -Include *.dll*, *.lic*);
$files|foreach($_){
   echo $_.Fullname;
   Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination ("$destdir" + "\" + "$_.Name") -Recurse;
}
```

Any ideas reagarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues going on here. First it is much better to use Join-Path to build paths than to try to build them yourself. Second, there is no need to put double quotes around any of the variables when building the path. Third, if you are going to use the unneeded double quotes, yoou need a $() around the $_.Name to force the property to be accessed as opposed to the .TOString() function of the object. Here is an alternative way to do that line:

```
Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination (Join-Path $destdir $_.Name) -Recurse;
```

Comment: Excellent recomendation but I'm still having the same issue doing it this way.

Comment: Then I would suspect a typo further up in the code. Is this all of your code?

Comment: Indeed this is the block that fails, when I remove this code the rest works perfectly.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not seeing the problem then. If I get a chance later I will try to mock up a test environment and replicate the issue.

Comment: Yes please, try doing it inside a windowsservercore:10.0.14393.206 container.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't have access to Docker so I may not be able to truly replicate the issue.